# How can I clear the cache of zsh autocorrect?

Tags: zsh

How can I clear the cache of zsh autocomplete.

E.g.  if I do:

```
> apt-get install rubygems
> gem
zsh: correct 'gem' to 'gdm' [nyae]? % n
RubyGems is a sophisticated package manager for Ruby.  This is a
basic help message containing pointers to more information.
...
```

How can I prevent the "correct 'gem' to 'gdm'" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer lies with something like hashing. See this StackOverflow answer for more.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437454/zsh-questioning-correct-command-how-to-stop